# Count of grouped values between dates selected in slicer

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a column, which counts the number of instances per group, but also adjusts based on a date slicer.
For example, client A has 10 calls in the entire dataset, client B has 15 calls in the entire dataset over several years. I have a date slicer to only display data for 2023, which works fine filtering the data and only displaying the records from 2023. However, my Count column does not respond to the date filter and displays the total call count.
Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZtSc.png)

Here is how I calculated the "Count" column:

Static Count =
CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[Call]),
FILTER(
ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[Client]),
'Table'[Another Field] <> "abc" && 'Table'[Another Field] <> "xyz"
)
)

I also created two measures, which get the MIN and Max dates of the Slicer:

Measure 1
Min Date =
CALCULATE(
MIN(Table[Date and Time]),
ALLSELECTED(Table[Date and Time])
)

Measure 2
Max Date =
CALCULATE(
MAX(Table[Date and Time]),
ALLSELECTED(Table[Date and Time])
)